How to deal with the removal of support of running multiple batch jobs at once?
Spring Batch recently removed the opportunity to run multiple batch jobs at once.
So now, you can still package multiple batch jobs into the same application but for every execution of the batch application you can only run one of those jobs.
I am using Spring Cloud Dataflow in order to execute my batchapplication via REST Requests.
Previously everything was easy since you could run multiple jobs (so 1 HTTP request to the SCDF server did the job) but now I have to make an HTTP Request for each job I want to execute. Each request boots the spring batch application, executes the job and shuts down the app. For 5 of my jobs this would be repeated 5 times, which adds a huge overhead to the total execution time of my workflow. Executing all 5 jobs on spring cloud dataflow takes about a minute, but the jobs in itself do not take a long time to execute, which is why most of the time is overhead provided by Spring during booting / shutting down the app.
Do you know any way to deal with this?
My first idea was to create another job that executes all of the steps of my 5 jobs sequentially, but I havent tried it out yet. Maybe someone knows an even better solution?

Have you considered a custom job launcher that launches all jobs sequentially?

You can use the composed task feature which means creating a task that will orchestrate all you batch jobs.
<task1 || task2 || task3> && task4
In this case task1, task2 and task3 will run in parallel and when completed task4 will be executed.
